# Please suggest some open source java event handling libraries

Tags: events, orm, event-handling, notifications, soa

I am looking for centralized event processing utility which can listen to events from different applications(possibly running on different app servers), I am searching for an open source solution which I can extend/tailor to may needs. This is what I am planning to do with it -

1. capture events from different applications
2. Check for filter condition
3. Based on filter condition call a webservice to update database or use hibernate or other ORM to update database

It would be helpful if you can suggest some libraries that I can look into,

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/about/esper/esper.html) which is an embedable open source complex event processing library